# How to pass variable to a view after submitting?

Tags: 7, forms

Why does the below code not work?  I am trying to pass the $_POST value to example_page() when I submit the form:

```
function example_menu () {
  $items['example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page_arguments' => array('example_form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}

function example_page($arg) {
  return "hello, $arg!";
}

function example_form($form,&$form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text',
    '#default_value' => t('Enter your name') 
  );
  return $form;
}

function example_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {
  //BELOW DOES NOT WORK, and forget about passing raw HTML to output
  return example_page($form_state['values']['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only assuming but I would imagine that the form is redirecting somewhere after your submit handler, that's why the result of `example_page` is not being displayed. Also I'm not sure if you're copying the code or written it on StackExchange but you're missing a `return` from your `hook_menu`

This is how you'd normally pass variables to pages:

```
function example_menu () {
  $items['example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page_arguments' => array('example_form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  $items['example/page/%'] = array( // % means variable
    'title' => 'Example arg',
    'page callback' => 'example_page',
    'page_arguments' array(2), // 0 is example, 1 is page, 2 is the % variable
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,    
  );
  return $items;
}

function example_page($arg) {
  return '$arg is: ' . $arg;
}

function example_form($form,&$form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text',
    '#default_value' => t('Enter your name') 
  );
  return $form;
}

function example_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {
  // No return from submit handler, but set redirect
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'example/page/' . $form_state['values']['name'];
}
```

Comment: I fixed the "return $items" from the hook_menu.  It was my mistyping.  Still, the problem is that I want example_page() to load up with the argument passed to it.  hook_form_submit is doing something.  It is so easy to do with PHP since you just say, if($_POST['name']) ... but there does not appear a way to grab $_POST values from Drupal 7.  It is not powerful enough?

Comment: @user785179 I've amended my answer to reflect how to pass variables to pages. Please have a look. Disclaiming that I didn't test the code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Your example works, but now I get ugly URL's because the values are being passed via $_GET.  Is there a way to do it using $_POST?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to return a string from a submit handler to have that string display: Drupal doesn't use submit handlers in that way. By default the form's action will point to the current URL, so after submission your form is displayed again. So effectively anything like displaying *Hello, arg* can be done from within `example_form` (or you can use the [post, redirect, get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) method Baysaa mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you have a mistake in your naming, hook_form can not be a valid form ID

change it to something else like example_form_test

Comment: Good eye! Unfortunately it doesn't change anything as I still cannot pass a variable to my view.  Is Drupal not powerful enough to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'view'? It has a very specific meaning in Drupal that I don't think you're referring to

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari Not true, that hook is only invoked for modules that also implement `hook_node_info()`

Comment: it seams the question is about posting data to a page callback function and is not related to `hook_form`